# How to save uploaded files in git repository after pushing?

Tags: git, upload, openshift

I use Openshift. It uses git - you just push and the server makes all deployments. Then I made an app that uploads pictures. Obviously, I upload them in git repo and after push all the pictures erase. What is the best practice to save pictures?

I tried:

1) pulling before pushing - no sense

2) gitignoring /media folder - no sense

I could try:

1) to deploy another service for photos only. My friends say it is weird decision and I will have the same problem if I want update that new server

2) somehow save the photos outside git repo but I have no idea how to implement it and no idea whether it is a good practice

Any adviсe? Looking forward to reading you.

Comment: Put your media files in other branch, and push this branch to openshift, and user other branch only for source code.

Comment: Have you looked into git-lfs?

Comment: @EdgardLeal, how can I access files in other branch from frontend? And how to upload them?

Comment: @BrianaSwift, the same question. This solution works for pre-loaded files only if I understand correctly and I need to upload files from web interface

Comment: See this guide to deploy on openshift using a diferent branch:

`$ rhc deploy <branch_name> -a <app>` https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/deployments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push any git, it is saved in a special directory which is stored in environment variable `OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR`. This directory always holds currently deployed version of the application.

Now, Openshift has other special directories which you can access via following environment variables `OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR`, `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`, `OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR`, `OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR`. OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR is the persistent data directory. Contents of this directory don't get erased after every git push. You should always save files in this directory, and this is a good practice. This is how Openshift works.

If your application handles uploaded images, modify the application code to save it in the data directory. You can use `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` environment variable to get the data directory location. How you can access environment variables in your application, will depend on the programming language you used.

in php,

```
$data_dir = getenv('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR');
```

in node.js

```
var dataDir = process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
```

For a list of environment variables used by Openshift, see [here](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/environment-variables.html).

Comment: Good! It's what I needed! And to access this data I need to write extra getter in my server to access this folder, correct?

Comment: Yes. In your server, get the data directory to a `variable` and use `variable/image.name` to save/get/modify the image from that directory.